# Tensorflow value: Shapes are incompatible

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp

my dataset has 23735 rows and 5 columns, 4 are int and 1 is string, string type is my target variable.

This is my code :

```
{#num_classes = 3

 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.20,random_state=42)
#label_encoder = LabelEncoder()

 # Fit label encoder on all labels
 #label_encoder.fit(y)

 # Encode the training labels
 #y_train_encoded = label_encoder.transform(y_train)

 # Encode the test labels
 #y_test_encoded = label_encoder.transform(y_test)


  #y_train_onehot = to_categorical(y_train_encoded, num_classes)
  #y_test_onehot = to_categorical(y_test_encoded, num_classes)


  model = Sequential(name='Sentiment_Analysis_using_3_Input_Features')
  model.add(Input(shape=(3,), name='Input_Layer'))
  model.add(Dense(2, activation='relu', name='Hidden_Layer'))
  model.add(Dense(3, activation='sigmoid', name='Output_Layer'))

   model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
          loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          metrics=['Accuracy', 'Precision', 'Recall'], 
          loss_weights=None,#
          weighted_metrics=None,
          run_eagerly=None, 
          steps_per_execution=None 
         )

    model.fit(X_train, y_train,
      batch_size=32,
      epochs=12,
      verbose='auto',
      callbacks=None,
      validation_split=0.2,
      shuffle=True,
      class_weight=None,
      sample_weight=None,
      initial_epoch=0,
      steps_per_epoch=594,  # samples - (test_size * samples) / batch_size
      validation_steps=None,
      validation_batch_size=32,  # same as batch size
      validation_freq=1,
      max_queue_size=10,
      workers=1,
      use_multiprocessing=False)


   y_pred_labels = model.predict_classes(X_test)
   class_labels = ['Positive', 'Negative', 'Neutral']


       }
```

I am receiving this error :

```
Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 3) are incompatible
```

Ive tried doing it by encoding but can't get it right.

Comment: Hi @M. Ali Siddique, as you have mentioned that there are 3 classes in your dataset then you need to use 'softmax' activation function in the last dense layer of the model. Please try again and let us know if the issue still persists.